# Fill the whole row of listbox selected items in form controls

Tags: c#, database, textbox, listbox

I have a text box, and I have written code on a textbox textchange event so that when I type any text, related text is retrieved from my database and shown in a listbox.

I want to be able to click on any name in the list box, and make the whole row related to that name show on form controls.

Comment: What form technology are you using? WPF? WinForms? ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you well, you would like to copy selected text (from a selected row in listBox) to textBox. You can easily do like it:

```
  private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      textBox1.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
  }
```

Mitja

Comment: by this code i can only show a particular item in text box from listbox. but i want whole row related to this should be shown in multiple textboxex or comboboxex.